# One column into multiple columns by type, plus concatenating multiples

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| Customer | Number | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234.567.8910 | 1 |
| 1 | 234.234.2345 | 2 |
| 2 | 234.567.5555 | 1 |
| 2 | 151.513.5464 | 1 |
| 3 | 845.846.8486 | 3 |

I am trying to include this information with information from another table (say... address), but in separate columns by type, and I want to concatenate values that are of the same type so that the return looks like this:

| Customer | Cell | Home | Work |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234.567.8910 | 234.234.2345 | NULL |
| 2 | 234.567.5555 & 151.513.5464 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | 845.846.8486 |

When I use the STRING_AGG function, it appends the value for each line of that customer - even if it would be null when the function isn't applied, so the customer 1 has both the cell and home numbers repeated twice.

The only workaround I can find is to select each column in a subquery and join them together. Is that the only option?

Answer (score 1):

You need conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    Customer,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN Number END, ' & ') Cell,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Type = 2 THEN Number END, ' & ') Home,
    STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Type = 3 THEN Number END, ' & ') Work
From table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `FOR XML` and `PATH`.

**Query**

```
select [Customer],
     stuff((
        select distinct ',' + [Number]
        from [your_table_name]
        where [Customer] = a.[Customer]
        and [Type] = 1
        for xml path (''))
        , 1, 1, '')  as [Cell],
    stuff((
        select distinct ',' + [Number]
        from [your_table_name]
        where [Customer] = a.[Customer]
        and [Type] = 2
        for xml path (''))
        , 1, 1, '')  as [Home],
    stuff((
        select distinct ',' + [Number]
        from [your_table_name]
        where [Customer] = a.[Customer]
        and [Type] = 3
        for xml path (''))
        , 1, 1, '')  as [Work]
from [your_table_name] as a
group by [Customer];
```